how to print this pattern using c programing language
1
0   1
0   1   0
1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   0   1

this is the pattern to be printed
I tried using various methods but I could not get the exact pattern
PS: I am a beginner at programming
the code given below does not give the desired output
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int start;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            start = 0;
        } else {
            start = 1;
        }


        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", (start + j) % 2);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 6;
    print_pattern(n);
    return 0;
}


Please [edit] your question to tell us what problems you have with the code you show. Doesn't it build? Does it give unexpected output? Or not working in some other way when you build or run it? And please copy-paste (as text) your full and complete assignment or exercise into your question. And actually ask a question.

Also please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

the code I have written does not give me the exact output

two loops, one inside the other, should be good enough. Don't worry about start... just keep switching from 0 to 1, and vice versa. You can use k = 1 - k;

Please explain why printf("1\n0\t1\n0\t1\t0\n1\t0\t1\t0\n1\t0\t1\t0\t1\n0\t1\t0\t1\t0\t1\n"); is not the answer, i.e. please explain the logic behind the desired output. Is there a known pattern in the background?

@ALLEN: you can accept en answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Seems to be some serious overthinking here. The printed digit merely flips between 0 and 1, starting at 1.
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(int n)
    {
    int digit = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            {
            printf("%d\t", digit);
            digit = !digit;
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
    }

int main(void)
    {
    print_pattern(6);
    }


I'd up-vote it if not for the evil coding style.

Here is a simple alternative: store the value to output in a variable and alternate between 0 and 1 after each printout.
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(int n) {
    int value = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%d   ", value);
            value = 1 - value;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}   

int main(void) {
    print_pattern(6);
    return 0;
}

Note that the value can also be computed from the row and column numbers:
void print_pattern(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%d   ", (i / 2 + j) % 2);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}   


#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts(
        "1\n"
        "0   1\n"
        "0   1   0\n"
        "1   0   1   0\n"
        "1   0   1   0   1\n"
        "0   1   0   1   0   1\n"
    );
}

Exact, fast, precise and readable!!! :)

But if you want a parametizable version, based on what you have shown (you don't specify how the pattern repeats):
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(int n)
{
    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {

        int start = ((row + 2) % 4) / 2;
        const char *sep = "";
        for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
            printf("%s%d", sep, start);
            sep = "   ";
            start = !start;
        }
        puts("");  /* print a newline */
    }
}

int main()
{
    print_pattern(10);
}

Will produce:
$ a.out
1
0   1
0   1   0
1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
$ _

Pattern repeats twice each four lines, so getting module 4 and dividing by two will identify the two starting points (well, we need to offset the row number first to make the sequence to start at the proper point.  This is the strangeness around ((row + 2) % 4) / 2.  As 4 is a power of two, the % 4 can be changed by & 3, and the / 2 by >> 1.  This tan make you see something like int start = ((row ^ 2) & 3) >> 1; as an equivalent expression.
Edit (Tue Jul  9 09:50:09 EEST 2024)
If you print your pattern without the intervening \n you will realize that you don't need to initialize the start value with the info of the row, as the numbers always repeat from 0 -> 1, then 1 -> 0, so the following code also prints the pattern:
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(int n)
{
    for (int row = 1, start = 0; row <= n; row++) {
        const char *sep = "";

        for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
            printf("%s%d", sep, ++start & 1);
            sep = "  ";
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int main()
{
    print_pattern(15);
}

the ones and zeros do alternate without relationship to the actual row or column they are printed on.

You should use mod 4 because of 0 0 1 1 pattern (first element of each rows), this pattern has 4 elements.

If mod 4 result is 1 or 2 --> start with 0
If mod 4 result is 0 or 3 --> start with 1


#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(int n) {
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int start;
    int tmp = i%4;
    if (tmp==1 || tmp==2) {
      start = 0;
    } else if(tmp==3 || tmp==0) {
      start = 1;
    }
    for(int x=1; x<i; x++) {
      printf("%d\t", (x+start)%2);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  int n = 9;
  print_pattern(n);
  return 0;
}


Or: start = ( ( i + 3 ) >> 1 ) & 1;

If you have taken tmp = i % 4;, then there's no reason for the else if (tmp == 3 || tmp == 0), as if tmp is not 1 or 2, it must be 3 or 0, no other possibility is acceptable.

A single loop will do the trick, with a condition to decide whether we've reached the end of a line, and then simply logically negating the digit on each iteration.
void print_pattern(int n) {
    int digit = 1;
    int rows = 1;
    int row_digit_count = 0;

    while (rows <= n) {
        printf("%d ", digit);
        digit = !digit;
        row_digit_count++;

        if (row_digit_count == rows) {
            printf("\n");
            rows++;
            row_digit_count = 0;
        }
    }
}

Now:
int main(void) {
    print_pattern(5);
}

Results in the following output:
1
0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1

